# OpenGL/GLUT - Updating several windows

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

So, I'm creating a game where I have two different windows which have different display functions. What I'm wondering is if it's possible to update two windows simultaneously. Let's say for one window, I implicitly call `glutPostRedisplay()` to force an update. This will only cause an update on the current window. Yet, I wanted to update both of them.

Is this even possible? I've been searching for quite a long time and didn't seem to some to a definitive answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [4.5 `glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node20.html)
>
> `glutPostRedisplay` marks the ***current window*** as needing to be redisplayed.

"Current window" eh?  I wonder if...

> [4.3 `glutSetWindow`, `glutGetWindow`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node18.html)
>
> `glutSetWindow` sets the current window; `glutGetWindow` returns the identifier of the current window.

```
foreach( int window : windows )
{
    glutSetWindow( window );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: I'm facepalming with my both hands and I fear I might have hurt myself during the process.

Comment: @AndréSilva: Eh, don't feel too bad, GLUT isn't exactly a paragon of API design :)